# jQuery Date Picker to show only months

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery Datepicker in my project. In that i have requirement, where i have to show all the months, similar like the date which we normally display.

I searched in the net, but i found only months in dropdown with in the datepicker. But that is not matching my requirement. Did any one used datepicker to show the only months and year.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"![enter image description here][2]>
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Some thing like this 
[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bopperben/DBpJe/

Comment: Please check this image, i was expecting like this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yLjDH/

Comment: You can use it by jquery month picker plugin follow this link [Month link](https://github.com/lucianocosta/jquery.mtz.monthpicker)

Comment: Could you please clarify? I don't understand what you need. Maybe provide some sort of screenshot to illustrate.

Comment: I use jQuery DatePicker in my project. So using the this plugin i want to show only months in the datepicker. Somthing similar to the screenshot in which is attached above.